# License Plate enhancement from video

Tags: video

I have a high res video where I'm trying to get the license plate off a black range rover that was used for a robbery.  If anyone has special skills that could get some digits from the plate, it would be greatly appreciated.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B15KCVlLS-cPWTNrQU85c3RLdzg

Thanks.

Comment: unlike what you may have seen in CSI, it is not possible to 'add' pixels that don't exist

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert and I'm not in USA so not familiar with the US plate system, but I've just used VLC player (free download available) with a crop adjustment made top and bottom to allow me to view the center of the video double sized on my monitor, then found a few frames where the plate looks clearest and taken a screen grab and into photoshop to zoom in. Looks to me like the first digit is a 5 and possibly the ending is Z1. It is somewhat fuzzy though, but there do seem to be a few frames where it's a bit clearer. I'd say there are some Cs in the middle or perhaps zeros.

Comment: It looks like a California plate so a leading "**5**" would not be unexpected.